# IPhone & IPad: Universal App, Which OS version do my users need?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

I have a universal app for ipad and iphone. What I'm trying to determine is what OS version do my users need to have in order for my app to work?

In Xcode, in the top left hand corner I see:
"Device - 4.0 | Release | MyAppName"

Does this mean they need to have ios 4.0? Also, the weird thing is that my ipad is running ios version 3.2.2 but for some reason it works when I build&run the program on the device...

Can anyone help me out on how this all works? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doen't restrict the minimum OS. In the build settings, **you should set the base SDK as high as possibile** (otherwise the newest devices may not be able to run it), but **set the iOS deployment target to as low as possibile** (the lowest for an universal app is 3.0 - but check if all your classes that you are using are available in 3.0), because this tells the min. iOS it can run on.

Comment: there's no "iOS deployment target" in there. Only "iphone deployment target" (which is currently set to 4.0 so I'll try setting it to 3.0). Shouldn't there be an ipad deployment target??

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, it's the same thing (iOS and iPhone OS), but it is renamed to iOS in newer versions of XCode. Download the latest one.